# In CentOS 6.6 yum update show some dependency error

Tags: linux, centos

When I update centos package it (sudo yum update). It shows following error like.

```
Error: Package: 1:control-center-2.28.1-39.el6.x86_64 (@server1)
   Requires: libgnome-desktop-2.so.11()(64bit)
   Removing: gnome-desktop-2.28.2-11.el6.centos.x86_64 (@server1)
       libgnome-desktop-2.so.11()(64bit)
   Updated By: gnome-desktop-2.32.0-13.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
       Not found
Error: Package: gthumb-3.2.4-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
   Requires: libgstreamer-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gthumb-3.2.4-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
   Requires: libtiff.so.5(LIBTIFF_4.0)(64bit)    
Error: Package: gnome-screensaver-2.28.3-28.el6.x86_64 (@server1)
       Requires: libgnome-desktop-2.so.11()(64bit)
       Removing: gnome-desktop-2.28.2-11.el6.centos.x86_64 (@server1)
           libgnome-desktop-2.so.11()(64bit)
       Updated By: gnome-desktop-2.32.0-13.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Not found
```

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodiges

It show after installing **nux-dextop**. I am using centos 6.6(64-bit). I am newly use centos.
Thanks in advance.

**Update : Solved :** 
In /etc/yum.repos.d/nux-dextop.repo file I made a small change.
change the line **enabled=1** to **enabled=0**. It shows no error.

thanks

Comment: Add [nux](http://ask.xmodulo.com/enable-nux-dextop-repository-centos-rhel.html]) repo list and then try.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in your nameserver /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 4.2.2.1

nameserver 4.2.2.2

or

nameserver 8.8.8.8

or check to whether the  repository URL ping your server.